# I need to make the vertices of a mesh follow a path / curve so that the mesh deforms as it follows the path?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, vertices, path

Edit: **During an animation**. I do not mean an extrude but animating the vertices of a mesh along a predefined path curve.

I have a mesh and a complex path curve. I'd like to make each individual row of vertices on the mesh follow the path. I don't know how to do this.

I currently have animall and standard latest version of blender. I can add any other extension i need to complete this task as it is crucial to the project i am making.

1) i have a custom path curve in two dimesional space (the third dimension is locked, static)

2) i have a mesh perpendicular to the path curve (mesh is in x - z and the curve is in y - x)

3) I want to make the mesh follow the path curve to get a nice animation of a piece of endless track rolling down a production line

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMCrM.jpg

Ignore the curve atm it's just a test curve. I want the mesh to deform according to the shape of the curve so i can fake the physics and make a fast and neat animation of a rather complex motion by making the path curve by hand.

I want the vertices of a mesh to follow the path (mesh deforms as it follows the path) with all vertices with the same Y coordinate moving in the same way.

edit: some styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press SHIFT + “C” to center the cursor.

In Front View (Press “1”) Press Shift + “A” and add a plane. Tab into Edit Mode and press CTRL + “R” and add a healthy number of Loop Cuts by scrolling your Mouse Wheel.
[image]

Tab into Object Mode and add a Bezier Curve by pressing SHIFT + A. Then Rotate the Bezier Curve 90’ on the “X” Axis. Press “R” “X” 90.

Select your Plane and add a Curve Modifier. In the Modifier Pane choose the Bezier Curve as the "Object"either with the “Eye Dropper” or enter in the name of the Bezier Curve.
[image]
[image]

Move (Animate) the Plane on the “X” Axis.
[image]

A Bezier Curve with more segments and a Sub Surf Modifier on the Plane.
[image]

Comment: **Thank you!** I think that this will be perfect. I will try this myself.

Comment: Interesting. Couldn't make it work, as each time I would try to move the object along the curve it would "break free" of the path into weird directions. I've had more luck with "follow path" constraint but I'm not sure this one can deform the mesh along the path

Answer (score 1):

Is this what u need. I understood from your question
[image]

This u need to do
Select the plane then the curve. Add more loop cut so that have smooth shape to the plane. And press ctrl+P and select follow path and play

How it works

[image]

Comment: adding more subdivisions to the plane will help make the shape follow the path as well.

Comment: @cegaton yeah its just to understand.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work as intended. Adding a curve modifier  as suggested in the Dontwalk's answer did. With smooth shading i'm going to get the result i want.

Comment: again, the key is subdividing the plane, else there is no deformation along the path.