# I want to roll the tape so that it follows the circle nicely

Tags: modeling, animation, bezier-curves

I want to roll the tape so that it lines up nicely with the cylinder.
[image]
When viewed from the front, the surface where the tape meets the cylinder is distorted as shown in the image.
[image]
Currently, I manually adjust the curve to follow the circle and add a curve modifier to the tape.

Is there any way to semi-automatically make the tape follow the circle?

---

I meant that I am looking for a way to make the CURVE in the following article follow the cylinder in a non-human-powered way.

●The article 
[I need to make the vertices of a mesh follow a path / curve so that the mesh deforms as it follows the path?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82940/i-need-to-make-the-vertices-of-a-mesh-follow-a-path-curve-so-that-the-mesh-def)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just increase the resolution preview of your curve:

[image]

or/and the resolution U:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It's smooth now!

However, I have one more question. If I want to follow many curves on a cylinder like this, it is very time consuming to adjust them manually, and it is difficult to follow the circle nicely. Is the SNAPS function the only way to do this?

Comment: Hi Hana. If my answer helped you, pls click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you. Pls do not ask additional questions in comments because other people might have the same question and won’t find possible answers in comments because the search engine of SE does not search in comments. You may ask as many questions as you want. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Sorry!
Thank you so much for your kind attention!
I'll ask the above question again if I'm ever in trouble again!
thanks again!